# MSSQL & Node.JS - Failed to connect to WIN-OTGKTVPUIFC:1433

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have a problem when connect to SQL Server.
My config connect SQL Server:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');

const configMsSql = {
    server:"myserver",
    port:myport,
    user:"username",
    password:"pass",
    database:"dbname",
    options:{
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
};

async function connectState(){
    const connect = await mssql.connect(configMsSql);
    console.log("Connect to SQL successfully!");
    return connect;
}

module.exports = connectState();
```

After run server. mssql throw error:

```
err = new ConnectionError(err)
                ^

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to WIN-OTGKTVPUIFC:1433 - 7C250000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1986:

    at C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1020:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1048:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1399:12)
    at C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2406:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to WIN-OTGKTVPUIFC:1433 - 7C250000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1986:

      at Connection.socketError (C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1399:28)
      at C:\UIS\SboxNode\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2406:25
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Although I enabled TCP/IP and field TCP Port used exactly.
[image]

I tried to search gg this error but the most answer that "enable TCP/IP".
I spent many time to fix but cant. Help me plzz :(

Comment: SQL Native Client 11.0 configuration? Have you considered upgrading from SQL Server 2012 yet, it's been unsupported for several years already. Modern SQL client libraries expect TLS 1.2 as a minimum encryption protocol, if you had been keeping up with SQL Server 2012 patches then it should have had [TLS 1.2 protocol support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe) already.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, how to upgrade as you recommend?

Comment: first of all, narrow down the problem, try connecting via port using sql management studio. if it doesn't work, theres something wrong on your setup. otherwise, see tedious docs, maybe something is missed. perhaps authentication type need to be explicitly specified.

Comment: also, checked tedious docs, the user creds are under [`authentication.options`](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/frequently-encountered-problems.html). maybe, check that also?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯